# How do I compute the infinity-norm of a function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functional

I have a technical question on Mathematica 11.

I have to compute the $\infty$ norm of q function, $f(x,y)$, on a rectangular domain $[a, b] \times [c,d]$. How can I do this with Mathematica?

Comment: By finding the minimun and the maximum of the function? `NMinimize` and `NMaximize` might help.

Comment: If you tell us what the function looks like, it might be easier to answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of an example I'll make up an example:

```
f[x_, y_] = {1, x, y, x^2, x y, y^2}.RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 6]
```

> 10 + x + 4 x^2 - 3 y - 10 x y + 7 y^2

Find the $\infty$-norm $\|f(x,y)\|_{\infty}$ on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$:

```
With[{a = -1, b = 1, c = -1, d = 1},
  NMaximize[{Abs[f[x, y]], a <= x <= b && c <= y <= d}, {x, y}]]
```

> {35., {x -> 1., y -> -1.}}

Comment: Thank you! I didn't specify the function because it's a very long Taylor expansion with some trigonometric terms, but since it's continous on my domain NMaximize works great.